# Trouble Compiling, Two programs open

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, codeblocks, c++builder

I have looked all over and asked all my college instructors and they have nothing.

When I am programming on my laptop, Im using C++ builder(RAD studio), Code-Blocks, and Visual Studio 2013. I get the same results every time.

Whenever I compile my code(build and run) Two programs pop up, and it doesn't matter whether its console or systems application. Two programs always pop up. Sometimes the first one glitches out and then the second program immediately starts. When the second program is finished or exited. Everything is normal (as it should have been).

Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: What are the two programs that appear?

Comment: @Crummy I think it's fair to assume that he means the one he is debugging. As for OP, I saw the exact same question weeks ago and nobody could help saying that it is a case-by-case issue. This is an issue with your system - not your IDE or code.

Comment: The two programs that appear are is what my code compiled to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Future reference to anyone else with this issue, as it was pointed out to me, the issue was the active scanner that Avast uses(I would assume other antivirus programs might act similarly)
I simply opened up the Avast user interface, -> settings-> Active protection-> File system Shield(little grear)-> Disabled "scan when opening" and added an exclusion to the IDE folder just in case.

I hope this doesnt cause any issues too much with security, I doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem once. Are you using an antivirus like Avast?

Comment: Upon investigation if i turn my antivirus shield off everything works beautifully